# How to update label on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I would like to update a label once I press one of the buttons.
Here is my code - I added a label (caled `label1`), now I have two issues:

1. It presents some gibberish
2. How do I update the label with text right when the user is pressing the Browse button?

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        startButton = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.start_Button)
        label1 = Label(self, text=self.lable_1)

        quitButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        startButton.grid(row=0, column=2)
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def lable_1(self):
        print('starting')

    def start_Button(self):
        def f():
            print('Program is starting')
        t = threading.Thread(target=f)
        t.start()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x50")
app = Window(root)
root.title("My Program")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `self.label1` to get access to `Label`. BTW: `self.label_1` is function and there is no sense to use it as text - `text=self.label_1`. BTW: `print` only sends text on screen - it doesn't assign value to variable - use `return` instead of `print` in function `label_1` and then you can do `text=self.lable_1()` - with `()` at the end.

Comment: BTW: in tkinter you can use `root.after(milisecond, function_name)` to run function periodically and maybe you will no need threads.

Comment: have you searched this site for an answer before asking this question? There are many examples of programs that update a label, and many that do it repeatedly without the use of threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.label['text']` to change text

(Minimal?) Working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # tk.Frame.__init__ creates self.master so you don't have to
        #self.master = master 

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
        start_button = tk.Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.on_click)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello")

        quit_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        start_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def on_click(self):
        self.label['text'] = "Starting..."

root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you guys, this helps me a lot. i searched many times before asking, im just new to coding and sometimes i just dont know how to positioning things in the right order, also this "self" thing is still too complex to me. in the examples you gave me it really make sense and helps a lot on understanding. thanks again!